# In opencv's solvePnP, what should I pass for objectPoints?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, augmented-reality, pose-estimation

[OpenCV docs for solvePnp](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga549c2075fac14829ff4a58bc931c033d)

In an augmented reality app, I detect the image in the scene so I know imagePoints, but the object I'm looking for (objectPoints) is a virtual marker just stored in memory to search for in the scene, so I don't know where it is in space. 
The book I'm reading(Mastering OpenCV with Practical Computer Vision Projects ) passes it as if the marker is a 1x1 matrix and it works fine, how? 
 Doesn't solvePnP needs to know the size of the object and its projection so we know who much scale is applied ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're looking for a physical object, you should pass the 3D coordinates of the points on the model which are mapped (by projection) to the 2D points in the image.  You can use any reference frame, and the results of the solvePnp will give you the position and orientation of the camera in that reference frame.

If you want to get the object position/orientation in camera space, you can then transform both by the inverse of the transform you got from solvePnp, so that the camera is moved to the origin.

For example, for a cube object of size 2x2x2, the visible corners may be something like:  `{-1,-1,-1},{1,-1,-1},{1,1,-1}.....`

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the 3D coordinates of the real-world object that you want to map with the image. The scaling and rotation values will depend on the coordinate system that you use.

This is not as difficult as it sounds. See [this blog post](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2010/03/19/quick-and-easy-head-pose-estimation-with-opencv-w-code/) on head pose estimation. for more details with code.